# Как сделать так чтоб было видно цифры при перетаскивании ползунка

Tags: html, html5, javascript

Всем привет, подскажите как сделать так, чтоб было видно меняющиеся цифры при перетаскивании ползунка
Я прочитал что это можно сделать с помощью Javascript с помощью атрибута onChange, но как использовать этот атрибут я незнаю.
вот код
...
<input type="range" id="size" min="100" max="300"><br>
....

Comment: Посмотрите варианты [jQuery UI][1].

   [1]:http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот самый простой вариант. Это при условии, что есть JQuery :

```
<input max="300" min="100" id="size" onchange="$('#sizevalue').text($('#size').val());" type="range">
<div id="sizevalue">0</div>
```

Comment: А так то да, обратите внимание на jQuery UI.

Comment: благодарствую)))